# How would I display the grid coordinates of my player?

Tags: javascript, html

In my attempt to finish this tutorial correctly I am attempting to display with x and y coordinates of my player in HTML, as well as my progression through my maze in % format (for example 83%). I realize I must utilize Trigonometry for the location in my **showProgress()** function, though how would I actually display the running x and y coordinates, or even said progression?

```
var player = {

    init: function () {
    this.x = 14.25;
    this.y = 14.25;
    this.direction = 0;
    this.angle = -190;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.movementSpeed = 0.040;
    this.turnSpeed = 3 * Math.PI / 180;
    this.move = function () {

        var moveStep = this.speed * this.movementSpeed;
        this.angle += this.direction * this.turnSpeed;
        var newX = this.x + Math.cos(this.angle) * moveStep;
        var newY = this.y + Math.sin(this.angle) * moveStep;
        if (!containsBlock(newX, newY)) {

            this.x = newX;
            this.y = newY;
        };
    };

    this.draw = function () {

        var playerXOnMinimap = this.x * minimap.cellWidth;
        var playerYOnMinimap = this.y * minimap.cellHeight;
        minimap.context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        minimap.context.beginPath();
        minimap.context.arc(minimap.cellWidth * this.x, minimap.cellHeight * this.y, minimap.cellWidth / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
        minimap.context.fill();
        var projectedX = this.x + Math.cos(this.angle);
        var projectedY = this.y + Math.sin(this.angle);
        minimap.context.fillRect(minimap.cellWidth * projectedX - minimap.cellWidth / 4, minimap.cellHeight * projectedY - minimap.cellHeight / 4, minimap.cellWidth / 2, minimap.cellHeight / 2);
    };
}
}
```

http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @Jhecht it probably just is a `<canvas>` elm

Comment: Endless is correct in that it's <canvas>:

 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 <canvas id="minimap"></canvas>
 <canvas id="infoBox"></canvas>
 <canvas id="titleBox"></canvas>